# Using the transformation $=\pi−$ show that $\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x= \frac\pi2 \int_0^π f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration

Using the transformation $x = \pi - t$  show that $$\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\pi} f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried applying the transformation $x=\pi-t$? Or is that what is giving you trouble?

Comment: The answer is in you question. Apply the substitution proposed. Then, you have a equality of the form $A = B - A$, which is equivalent to the equality $A = \frac{B}{2}$. Just find out who are $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To prove:** $\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{\pi} f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x$ 
Let $I=\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x.$ Substitute $t=\pi-x \implies dt=-dx$. At $x=0,t=\pi$ and at $x=\pi, t=0$
$\implies I=\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\pi} (\pi-t)f (\sin (\pi-t)) \mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\pi} \pi f(\sin t) -tf(\sin t) \mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\pi} \pi f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi} \pi f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x-I$
$\implies I= \int_0^{\pi} \pi f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x-I\implies 2I= \int_0^{\pi} \pi f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the definite integral:
$$\begin{split}I&=\int_0^{\pi} xf (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x\\&= \int_0^{\pi} (\pi-t)f (\sin (\pi-t)) \mathrm{d}x\\&=  \int_0^{\pi} (\pi-x)f (\sin x) \mathrm{d}x\\\end{split}$$
Can you proceed on?

Comment: Thank you. I proceeded and found . What should I do next? Does this alone proves it?

Comment: @otnemem you Have $I$ on both sides, so rearrange the equation to find an expression for it